# What is the right way of handling the profile image in react native Image component?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am working on react native(0.57) and using the Flatlist to show list of available users in the contacts section. Each List Item shows - profile image and name.

Q1: What is the best way to load profile image from the server. I have the following options:

1. Each user's profile image must have a fixed url -> But in this case,
   image does not refresh automatically if the profile image changes on
   the server. May be due to caching issue.
2. Each user's profile image url must be changing -> In this case how
   can I tell the app to remain show the older profile image until the
   new image loads instead of showing a fixed placeholder dummy image.

Q2: Should I always request latest image URL from the server and then fetch the image from that new url or I must host the image as directory listing typz with authentication.

May I following the wrong approach? I apologize if it is very simple and obvious to implement but I am confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really depends on your server, assuming you're using a NodeJS Express server, then you would be making API requests to your server with the following link: `http://localhost:5000` or something along those lines.

Now on your client side (React Native) you should be making a HTTP request to your server side every time you need a users profile, I.E: If you click view profile your client side will make a request to your server side (possibly: `http://localhost:5000/api/getProfile/userID`) then your server side will send the response of the latest user profile information and on the client side you can save it in temporary storage like `Redux` and display it with your rendering logic.

Comment: Do I need to do something to save the image thumbnail in some cache or external storage or react native will do that  for me?

Comment: For example, if the user has off the internet, then will it be safe to assume that previously loaded images will continue to show or I must manually store these thumbnail in some storage (internal/external)?

Comment: To save images offline and use the data offline, then your image will probably need to be binary data rather than a link, and you'll need to use a storage system like `redux-persist` (https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) to keep that data saved on the app, even when the app is closed.

Depending on your app, you probably shouldn't let the user use the app without internet anyways, especially if it requires a lot of rendering from the server to properly function, in my opinion at least. As long as you saved the binary data of the images then yes the app will still show it offline.

Comment: how can I stop Image component to avoid caching from the same image URL, if my image changes from the server?

Comment: Is there any way to delete the cache for a specific URL. BTW, I am using native base as UI library and working with Thumbnail component for showing Image in the List on the contacts page.

Comment: You want to use a variable on the front end rather than a URL so imagine sending a request to your server, you will get some response like this: [{ imageURI: 'http://someimage.com' }], you would then use the imageURI variable and whenever you view that profile, the client will make a request to the server and the server will give the most updated link. Your client should constantly get updates from your server, but not like every second, only when a user clicks that specific profile.